Is there a clean way in Flutter/Dart GoRoute to pass an optional route?
Is there a cleaner way to do this? That is, use an optional route as an argument injected into
GoRoute(
  path: 'results',
  pageBuilder: (context, state) {
    final data = Provider.of<ResultsRouteData>(context);
    return SessionResultsScreen(data: data, levelUp: false);
  }
),

GoRoute(
  path: 'results/:levelUp',
  pageBuilder: (context, state) {
    final data = Provider.of<ResultsRouteData>(context);
    return SessionResultsScreen(data: data, levelUp: true);
  }
),


There's an update here. GoRouterState.getParams was changed to GoRouterState.getParameters in Flutter 7.0.0. Read about it here: Flutter: go_router how to pass multiple parameters to other screen?
I fixed my original problem with: final levelUp = state.uri.queryParameters['levelUp'];, which also worked for my GoRouter redirect version of the issue.

Yes, it depends on which version you use.

To use a query parameter instead of a path parameter in your GoRoute setup, you can modify the route to extract the levelUp value from the query parameters. Here’s how you can do it:
GoRoute(
  path: 'results',
  pageBuilder: (context, state) {
    final data = Provider.of<ResultsRouteData>(context);
    final levelUp = state.queryParams['levelUp'] == 'true'; // Retrieve the query parameter and convert to bool
    return SessionResultsScreen(data: data, levelUp: levelUp);
  },
),

Explanation:

path: 'results':

The route is defined for 'results' with no path parameters.


state.queryParams['levelUp'] == 'true':

This retrieves the value of the levelUp query parameter from the URL.
It compares the value with 'true' to determine if levelUp should be true or false.



Example URLs:

results:

The screen will load with levelUp set to false (default when the query parameter is not provided).


results?levelUp=true:

The screen will load with levelUp set to true.


results?levelUp=false:

The screen will load with levelUp set to false.



This setup is more flexible and keeps your routing clean by using query parameters to control optional behavior.

Thanks @Alessio. Is there something similar I could use in a GoRoute redirect (instead of a pageBuilder)? I have a place where I'm just redirecting instead of building a page. It looks like state.queryParams isn't permissible in that case.

Hello,
If I understand what you mean correctly, of course it can be done. I for example use redirect on the path "/" when using Keycloack as an authentication method, I get redirected to my app. Inside the redirect method I use query params to get the code parameter that is used to get the token.

There's a problem in this that deals with the Flutter version, and it was messing me up. See my posting below.
